# Seeking in my MemoryStream is having undesired results

Tags: c#, arrays, memorystream, binaryreader, binarywriter

I am working on re-writing our encryption class to be FIPS compliant, and in doing so have to re-work how we're handling non-secret payload data. At the moment, I'm writing out the size of my non-secret payload, then writing the size of my IV. I follow that up by writing my non-secret payload and IV, with all of these writes sharing a `BinaryWriter`. Lastly, I then share the same `MemoryStream` and write my the data needing to be encrypted into the the `CryptoStream`.

This is what the class currently looks like:

```
public class Encryption
{
    private const int SaltBlockSize = 8;
    private const int SaltBitSize = 64;
    private const int KeyBitSize = 256;
    private const int SaltIterations = 10000;

    private const int nonSecretPayloadOffsetInPayload = 0;
    private const int ivOffsetInPayload = 1;

    public byte[] GetNonSecretPayload(byte[] completePayload)
    {
        byte[] nonSecretPayload;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(completePayload))
        {
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream))
            {
                int nonSecretPayloadLength = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                binaryReader.BaseStream.Position = 3;
                nonSecretPayload = binaryReader.ReadBytes(nonSecretPayloadLength);
            }
        }

        return nonSecretPayload;
    }

    public byte[] EncryptMessageWithPassword(byte[] secretMessage, string password, byte[] nonSecretPayload = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can not provide an empty password, you must give a string that is at least 12 characters in size. If you just want to obfuscate the message without any protection, an alternative way is to use a Base64 String");
        }
        else if (password.Length < 12)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The minimum size your password can be is 12 characters.");
        }

        byte[] saltHash;
        byte[] saltKey = this.CreateSaltKeysFromPassword(password, 0, out saltHash);

        byte[] encryptedValue = null;

        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aesProvider.Key = saltKey;
            aesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesProvider.GenerateIV();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Write our IV out first so we can pull the IV off later during decryption.
                // The IV does not need to be encrypted, it is safe to store as as unencrypted buffer in the encrypted byte array.
                using (BinaryWriter ivWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
                {
                    // The first two writes to the stream should be the size of the non-secret payload
                    // and the size of the IV. If no payload exists, then we write 0.
                    if (nonSecretPayload == null || nonSecretPayload.Length == 0)
                    {
                        ivWriter.Write(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ivWriter.Write(nonSecretPayload.Length);
                    }
                    ivWriter.Write(aesProvider.IV.Length);

                    // If we have a payload, write it out.
                    if (nonSecretPayload != null && nonSecretPayload.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ivWriter.Write(nonSecretPayload);
                    }

                    // Write the Initialization Vector.
                    ivWriter.Write(aesProvider.IV);
                }

                // Create our encryptor and write the secret message to the encryptor stream.
                var encryptor = aesProvider.CreateEncryptor(saltKey, aesProvider.IV);
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(secretMessage, 0, secretMessage.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                }

                // Get the non-secret payload, IV, payload and IV lengths and encrypted data back as an array of bytes.
                encryptedValue = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public string EncryptMessageWithPassword(string secretMessage, string password, byte[] nonSecretPayLoad = null)
    {
        byte[] secreteMessageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretMessage);
        byte[] encryptedMessage = this.EncryptMessageWithPassword(secreteMessageBytes, password, nonSecretPayLoad);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedMessage);
    }

    private byte[] CreateSaltKeysFromPassword(string password, int nonSecretPayloadSize, out byte[] saltHash)
    {
        byte[] saltKey;

        //Use Random Salt to prevent pre-generated weak password attacks.
        using (var generator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltBitSize / SaltBlockSize, SaltIterations))
        {
            // Get a generated salt derived from the user password, hashed n-times where n = SaltIterations
            saltHash = generator.Salt;

            //Generate Keys
            saltKey = generator.GetBytes(KeyBitSize / SaltBlockSize);
        }

        return saltKey;
    }
}
```

I would expect  in my `GetNonSecretPayload(byte[] payload);` that by setting the position, or using `binaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(2);` to skip the IV length item, I would skip the IV size entry in the byte[] array and be able to read the bytes associated with the actual non-secret data. This doesn't work though, presumably because this isn't an array underneath the covers that I can just move to the next element in the array, skipping the IV length wrote out originally.

I have the following unit test.

```
[TestClass]
public class EncryptionTests
{
    private const string _ContentToEncrypt = "This is a test to make sure the encryption Type actually encrypts the data right.";

    private const string _Password = "EncryptedPassword1";

    [TestMethod]
    public void Extract_non_secret_payload_content_from_encrypted_string()
    {
        // Arrange
        var encryption = new Encryption();
        string nonSecretData = "My payload is not considered secret and can be pulled out of the payload without decrypting";

        // Convert the secret and non-secret data into a byte array
        byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nonSecretData);
        byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_ContentToEncrypt);

        // Encrypt the secret data while injecting the nonsecret payload into the encrypted stream.
        byte[] encryptedValue = encryption.EncryptMessageWithPassword(encodedBytes, _Password, payload);

        // Act
        // Pull the non-secret payload out of the encrypted message - without having to decrypt it.
        byte[] UnencryptedPayloadWithinEncryptedArray = encryption.GetNonSecretPayload(encryptedValue);
        string payloadContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(UnencryptedPayloadWithinEncryptedArray);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(nonSecretData, payloadContent);
    }
}
```

What I get with my current `binaryReader.BaseStream.Position = 3` is

> "\0\u0010\0\0\0My payload is not considered secret and can be pulled out of the payload without decry"

I've read and wrote data like this in the past using a BinaryWriter, but I've never had to seek through it in order to skip data. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have 2 int32s before your unencrypted text, you need to be at position 8, because they are both 4 bytes long, either by setting the position, or simply just reading 2 int32s (you don't even need to store the second one, just read and ignore it).

Comment: Ok, I was manually setting the position at 8 earlier and I found for short strings being stored as non-secret data, it worked but if the string was long like in my example, it would still show leading data as those unknown values and truncate the end of the actual content. I'll just read the data and move forward, I was wanting to seek so I could avoid any performance penalties it might have. Wasn't sure as I couldn't find anything on seeking being faster than just reading. I assumed seeking was faster because it didn't have to do any conversion of data during the read.

Comment: I must have goofed something up earlier when testing. Setting `memoryStream.Position = 8` worked like a charm. Thanks!